# Audio sources not working twice in Android browser

Tags: android, html, html5-audio

In my project i have two audios, which i have added inside HTML as follows:

```
<audio  id="sample1">
    <source src="sample1.mp3" type='audio/mpeg; codecs="mp3"' preload="auto" />
    <source src="sample1.ogg"; codecs="vorbis"' preload="auto" />
</audio>
<audio  id="sample2">
    <source src="sample2.mp3" type='audio/mpeg; codecs="mp3"' preload="auto" />
    <source src="sample2.ogg" type='audio/ogg; codecs="vorbis"' preload="auto" />
</audio>
```

I have two buttons to switch between those two:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var audio =null;
 $('#button1').click(function(){
     if(audio!=null){
           audio.pause();
     }
    audio =null; 
    audio=$('#sample1');
    audio.play();
});

$('#button2').click(function(){
     if(audio!=null){
           audio.pause();
     }
    audio =null; 
    audio=$('#sample2');
    audio.play();
});
}
```

The problem is that, these audios work for the first time irrespective of order, but once an audio is played and is asked to repeat no audio is heard. (Eg: 2 is clicked. Audio works. Then 1 is clicked, audio works but next time on clicking either one no sound is heard).

This problem seems to exist only in the Android browser. Its working perfectly in Chrome browser in android and also on all browsers of PC.